# Expressing incomplete gamma function in term of certain list of functions.

Tags: functions, special-functions

In my application I need to code [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) on CUDA, preferably not as a convergent series, but as a closed expression in term of [certain functions that GPU supports](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE). The list includes elementary functions, erf, complete gamma, and Bessel functions.

I wonder whether there is a closed expression for incomplete gamma based on those. Even more interesting, a general question: how does one figures out whether a specific function is expressible in term of a given list of functions?

Comment: Seems you can calculate the ordinary gamma function with different CUDA instructions. What is the span of $x$ (lower integral limit) you will need for the incomplete one?

Comment: @mathreadler: any, 0 to $\infty$

Comment: What is the purpose of the CUDA code, to produce one output of the function at a time sporadically or to help calculate lots of values in a batch? There seem to be quite some interdependencies you can use if you want to calculate many values.

Comment: @mathreadler, that's irrelevant to the question. I think I just found an answer though, from the recurrence relation.

Comment: I have never come across an approximation (even a low-accuracy one) for incomplete gamma functions in closed form. I think the best you can do is to combine elementary functions provided by CUDA's standard math library with various expansions. An example of this approach would be the algorithm shown in the following paper: N. M. Temme, "A Set of Algorithms for the Incomplete Gamma Functions", *Probability in the Engineering and Informational Sciences*, Volume 8, Issue 2, April 1994, pp. 291-307 [(online)](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/10080/10080D.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use the formula in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function):

$$\gamma(s,x) = s^{-1}x^se^{-x}M(1,s+1,x)$$
Where M is some **Kummers confluent hypergeometric function**:
$$M(1,s+1,x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\prod_{m=1}^k(s+m)}$$

This function if you do step-wise factorization you realize you can calculate with an iterative approach consisting of two steps:

1. multiply something by $s+m$
2. multiply something by $x$

CUDA would benefit from splitting the sum up into partial sums. So that would be a second step to think about.